# Julia request user input from script

Tags: julia

How do I request user input from a running script in Julia? In MATLAB, I would do:

```
result = input(prompt)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is `readline(stdin)`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: We could stand to have a more sophisticated readline-library-like system for this, but for now this will do the trick. Keno's pure Julia reimplementation of our repl will give provide a nice framework for doing interactive stuff like this.

Comment: On julia 0.7 and later (possibly 0.6) this is now `stdin`.

Answer (score 19):

I like to define it like this:

```
julia> @doc """
           input(prompt::AbstractString="")::String

       Read a string from STDIN. The trailing newline is stripped.

       The prompt string, if given, is printed to standard output without a
       trailing newline before reading input.
       """ ->
       function input(prompt::AbstractString="")::String
           print(prompt)
           return chomp(readline())
       end
input (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> x = parse(Int, input());
42

julia> typeof(ans)
Int64

julia> name = input("What is your name? ");
What is your name? Ismael

julia> typeof(name)
String

help?> input
search: input

  input(prompt::AbstractString="")::String

  Read a string from STDIN. The trailing newline is stripped.

  The prompt string, if given, is printed to standard output without a trailing newline before reading input.

julia>
```

Comment: Nice answer, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A function that checks that the answer provided matches the expected Type:

Function definition:

```
function getUserInput(T=String,msg="")
  print("$msg ")
  if T == String
      return readline()
  else
    try
      return parse(T,readline())
    catch
     println("Sorry, I could not interpret your answer. Please try again")
     getUserInput(T,msg)
    end
  end
end
```

Function call (usage):

```
sentence = getUserInput(String,"Write a sentence:");
n        = getUserInput(Int64,"Write a number:");
```

Answer (score 2):

Now in Julia 1.6.1, it's as simple as typing:

```
num = readline()
```

Yea! without any arguments since *the default value for the IO positional argument of the readline() function* is "**stdin**". So in the above example Julia will read the input from the user and store it in the variable "**num**".

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer, please upvote.  This seems to be somewhat a common problem with Julia, where many stackoverflow highly voted/accepted answers are out of date.  By the way, note this functionality hasn't worked in VS Code for over 4 years, which I believe is the "standard" editor for Julia.  See https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/785

Answer (score -4):

First I ran
Pkg.add("Dates")
then

```
using Dates

println()
print("enter year  "); year = int(readline(STDIN))
print("enter month "); month = int(readline(STDIN))
print("enter day   "); day = int(readline(STDIN))

date = Date(year, month, day)
println(date)
```