# Julia: read, readline or something else?

Tags: input, julia

I want to ask several times to the user to input integers, floats and sometimes fractions.
I've been reading the docs but I'm confused about what's the best way to store user input. Should I use read, readline or something else?
Let's consider integers:

```
print("Input an integer: ")
n = read(STDIN,UInt8)
println(n)                        #returns the ASCII number correspondent 
                                  #to the first input character

print("Input an integer: ")
n = parse(UInt8,readline(STDIN))
println(n)                        #returns the input number correctly
                                  #but I wonder if there is a better way to do it
```

Comment: `readline` looks solid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia request user input from script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479782/julia-request-user-input-from-script)

Comment: @user3580870 no it isn't :( , it doesn't have GNU readline support for example, meaning you can't do things like move the cursor along the input line with ie. `Right Arrow` (to correct a typo, for example) you would get `^[[D` instead, see also: [#9867](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9867) and [#9851](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/9851). I'll try to implement this again, now that I understand how the new REPL works ...thanks to [LispREPL](https://github.com/swadey/LispREPL.jl/blob/master/src/LispREPL.jl)! :D

Comment: You should not ask for input from a user at all. It's more useful to write functions that take arguments, and have the user call the function with the arguments they want.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to do this is to use the `readline` function. Note that the `STDIN` parameter is not needed, as `readline` will read from STDIN by default.

```
print("Input an integer: ")
n = parse(UInt8, readline())
```

See `Input` for more details on ways to get input from the standard input streams.