# How can i get a integer or array of input in julia?

Tags: julia

i wanna write a code in julia, and i need input some data like c code(that explain below). how can i do this in julia?

> in c code we wrote:

```
 printf(" number = \n ");

scanf("%d", &N);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia request user input from script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479782/julia-request-user-input-from-script)

Comment: @Gnimuc i don't need input string, i wanna input multiple data,like input integer and array.

Comment: Stuff read from input is strings. You can extract elements from it with eval and parse, e.g. `eval(parse("[2, 3]"))`. But the more important question is, why would you do it? Julia runs live in the console, so normally you don't have to build artificial user-facing interactivity. You can write the functions and assume the user knows Julia.

Comment: @PatelMinhaj - Please stop appending "thanks in advance" in all these edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `readline` for getting input, and `parse(T,s)` for parsing a string `s` into type `T`. Example

```
julia> s = readline()
1 # readline blocks until it sees \n, I typed the "1 enter" here
"1\n"

julia> parse(Int, chomp(s))
1
```

The above example uses Julia 0.5, `readline` will remove the "\n" by default in 0.6 and later. And another user mentioned, with the REPL you rarely need to do this.