# How is "user input" suposed to work in Julia?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I am trying to pick up Julia and I wanted to program a tiny game where the user would guess a random number from [0-9]. But, user input does not work for me and I don't understand why.

I am on Windows 10, Visual Studio 1.37.1 (with Julia extension), Julia 1.2.0.

I have tried to get user input on the REPL, no problem.

Now if I put the exact same code in a script and `julia < my_script.jl`, it does not work. The script runs, but it does not let me write anything.

```
x = readline(); println(x)
```

This is the code that works in REPL, but not in script

I expect the script to halt, let me enter the input then print what I have entered, but it does not stop for me to write anything and just prints an empty line.

Comment: You could try to use this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23342933/2374329) from a related question, I could not reproduce the issue you describe. Try with `println("type something now: "); x = readline(); println(x)` this way the program prompts you for input and it's easier to see when it's ready for your input, or try with the linked function `println(input("type something now: "))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the terminal (or at the command prompt for Windows), type `julia my_script.jl` instead of `julia < my_script.jl`.

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Ah, I missed how the OP was calling the script wrongly.